# .blur not working after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to make simple  validation. It is working fine on first time but after filling the value in text if you refresh the page by pressing F5 then code will not work correctly.

Step to produce the bug

1. Focus on first text box and blur without filling any value. function will alert "error" and class named error will add on text box
2. now will value in text box and press F5. Then delete value from text box and blur function will alert 'no error' here is problem. it should alert because we are blur on empty text box.

I invested-gate and found this problem is occuring because of onload function where I mention code if input text value not equal to blank then blur text box

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $('input').blur(function(){
          if($(this).hasClass('error')){
             alert('error')
          }
          else {
             alert('no error')
         }
     }) 
  })

  function test(id){
     if($(id).val()==''){
       $(id).addClass('error')
     }
     else {
       $(id).removeClass('error')
     }
  }

  $(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
          $('input').each(function(){
             if($(this).val()!=''){
                $(this).blur();
             }
          })
     },1000)
  })
</script>
<style>
    .error{ border:#F00 solid 1px}
</style>
</head>


<body>
    <input type="text" onblur="test(this)"/>
    <input type="text" onblur="test(this)" />
</body>
```

Comment: Which prowser and which jquery version are you using?

Comment: i am using 1.8.3 version and mozilla firefox

Comment: actually on first time test() function execute first but on page refresh .blur function executing first

Comment: this method execute first jquery blur function then execute event blur $(this).blur();

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you check for the value at the time of determining if the input box is empty or not, instead of css class.

```
$('input').blur(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
        alert('error')
    } else {
        alert('no error')
    }
});
```

I think FF tries to preserve the state of the HTML document and so the class remains applied to the element

Answer (score 0):

***Just Try With The Following :***

**Script Part :**

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function test(textId){    
     if($("#"+textId).val()==""){
       $("#"+textId).addClass("error"); 
       alert("Error"); 
       setTimeout(function(){
       $("#"+textId).focus();
       },100);
       return false;
     }
     else {
       $("#"+textId).removeClass("error");
       alert("No Error");
       return true;
     }
  }
  </script>
```

**HTML Part :**

```
<style>
    .error{ border:#F00 solid 1px}
</style>
<body>
    <input type="text" onblur="test(this.id);" id="text1" value=""/>
    <input type="text" onblur="test(this.id);" id="text2" value=""/>
</body>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.